# How to sort after a groupBy in Rx

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have the following response from one of my surveys. Idea is to print the titles in the order of their popularity. So I grouped the topics by their titles and printing them in the order of their popularity. I am unable to figure out how to sort them after grouping. Appreciate any help.

**My Code**

```
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;
import rx.Observable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines;

public class FileProcess
{
    public static Map<Integer, String> LOOKUP = Maps.newConcurrentMap();

    static
    {
        LOOKUP.put(1, "Job Workflow for Connexus using Camel Activiti and the Oracle Grid Engine");
        LOOKUP.put(2, "Observe Don't Bake");
        LOOKUP.put(3, "Model Driven Development with EMF");
        LOOKUP.put(4, "Entity Resolution and Keying");
        LOOKUP.put(5, "Business Activity Monitoring");
        LOOKUP.put(6, "Scorecard Design 101");
        LOOKUP.put(7, "Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop");
        LOOKUP.put(8, "Java 7 & 8 New Features");
        LOOKUP.put(9, "A tale of a leaking class loader");
        LOOKUP.put(10, "AOP usecases - Demonstration in.Net with Unity and Postsharp");
        LOOKUP.put(11, "Functional Programming with F#");
        LOOKUP.put(12, "UI Test Automation @ $100/year");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        List<String> strings = readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/Users/p0c/Desktop/fav1.txt"));

        Observable.from(strings)
                .filter(line -> !line.endsWith("respondent's answers"))//ignore surveymonkey log
                .map(line -> replaceIndexWithTitle(line))//normalize
                .map(line -> removeIndexAsPrefix(line))//normalize
                .map(line -> line.toLowerCase())
                .groupBy(line -> line)
                .subscribe(observable ->
                                observable.count().subscribe(integer ->
                                                System.out.println(integer + "\t" + observable.getKey())
                                )
                );
    }

    private static String removeIndexAsPrefix(String line)
    {
        if (Character.isDigit(line.trim().charAt(0)))
        {
            return line.trim().substring(line.indexOf(".") + 1);
        }
        return line;
    }

    private static String replaceIndexWithTitle(String line)
    {
        if (Ints.tryParse(line.trim()) != null)
        {
            return LOOKUP.get(Ints.tryParse(line));
        }
        return line;
    }
}
```

**Current Output**

```
1   a tale of a leaking class loader
4   job workflow for connexus using camel, activiti and the oracle grid engine
1   observe don't bake
1   aop usecases - demonstration in .net with unity and postsharp
5   scorecard design 101
15  java 7 & 8 new features
1   job workflow for connexus using camel activiti and the oracle grid engine
16  introduction to hadoop and developing for hadoop
1   business activity monitoring
1   ui test automation @ 100/year
4   model driven development with emf
5   functional programming with f#
1   didn't attend
9   ui test automation @ $100/year
3   entity resolution and keying
```

**Sample Responses**

```
8
1/14/2015 4:54 PM View respondent's answers
Job Workflow for Connexus using Camel, Activiti and the Oracle Grid Engine
1/14/2015 4:10 PM View respondent's answers
Didn't attend
1/14/2015 11:21 AM View respondent's answers
Java 7 & 8 New Features
1/13/2015 1:17 PM View respondent's answers
functional programming with f#
1/13/2015 1:08 PM View respondent's answers
7.Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop
1/13/2015 12:44 PM View respondent's answers
7
1/13/2015 11:11 AM View respondent's answers
6
1/13/2015 10:41 AM View respondent's answers
Java 7 & 8 New Features
1/13/2015 10:38 AM View respondent's answers
Java 7 & 8 New Features
1/13/2015 10:14 AM View respondent's answers
7
1/13/2015 9:56 AM View respondent's answers
UI Test Automation @ $100/year
1/13/2015 9:48 AM View respondent's answers
AOP usecases - Demonstration in .Net with Unity and Postsharp
1/13/2015 9:22 AM View respondent's answers
6.Scorecard Design 101
1/13/2015 9:17 AM View respondent's answers
6
1/13/2015 9:08 AM View respondent's answers
UI Test Automation @ $100/year
1/13/2015 9:06 AM View respondent's answers
4.Entity Resolution and Keying
1/13/2015 9:02 AM View respondent's answers
Java 7 & 8 New Features
1/13/2015 9:01 AM View respondent's answers
Job Workflow for Connexus using Camel, Activiti and the Oracle Grid Engine
1/13/2015 8:57 AM View respondent's answers
6
1/13/2015 8:55 AM View respondent's answers
Job Workflow for Connexus using Camel, Activiti and the Oracle Grid Engine
1/13/2015 8:54 AM View respondent's answers
Java 7 & 8 New Features
1/13/2015 8:54 AM View respondent's answers
7.Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop
1/13/2015 8:48 AM View respondent's answers
8
1/13/2015 8:48 AM View respondent's answers
UI Test Automation @ $100/year
1/13/2015 8:47 AM View respondent's answers
6
1/13/2015 8:47 AM View respondent's answers
UI test automation @ 100/year
1/13/2015 8:44 AM View respondent's answers
Model Driven Development with EMF
1/13/2015 8:42 AM View respondent's answers
Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop
1/13/2015 8:42 AM View respondent's answers
12
1/13/2015 8:42 AM View respondent's answers
Java 7 & 8 New Features
1/13/2015 8:37 AM View respondent's answers
1
1/13/2015 7:40 AM View respondent's answers
UI Test Automation @ $100/year
1/12/2015 10:10 AM View respondent's answers
Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop
1/11/2015 9:34 AM View respondent's answers
1.Job Workflow for Connexus using Camel, Activiti and the Oracle Grid Engine
1/8/2015 5:07 PM View respondent's answers
Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop
1/8/2015 2:55 PM View respondent's answers
Java 7 & 8 New Features
1/8/2015 2:09 PM View respondent's answers
Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop
1/8/2015 1:36 PM View respondent's answers
Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop
1/8/2015 1:08 PM View respondent's answers
Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop
1/8/2015 1:02 PM View respondent's answers
UI Test Automation @ $100/year
1/8/2015 12:44 PM View respondent's answers
Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop
1/8/2015 12:31 PM View respondent's answers
UI Test Automation @ $100/year
1/8/2015 12:21 PM View respondent's answers
12.UI Test Automation @ $100/year
1/8/2015 12:04 PM View respondent's answers
8
1/8/2015 12:01 PM View respondent's answers
Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop
1/8/2015 11:58 AM View respondent's answers
Java 7 & 8 New Features
1/8/2015 11:56 AM View respondent's answers
4.Entity Resolution and Keying
1/8/2015 11:56 AM View respondent's answers
7
1/8/2015 11:53 AM View respondent's answers
Model Driven Development with EMF
1/8/2015 11:51 AM View respondent's answers
Introduction to Hadoop and Developing for Hadoop
1/6/2015 11:54 AM View respondent's answers
Java 7 & 8 New Features
1/5/2015 1:14 PM View respondent's answers
3.Model Driven Development with EMF
1/5/2015 11:55 AM View respondent's answers
11.Functional Programming with F#
1/5/2015 11:50 AM View respondent's answers
Java 7 & 8 New Features
1/5/2015 11:44 AM View respondent's answers
Entity Resolution and Keying
1/5/2015 10:26 AM View respondent's answers
Model Driven Development with EMF
1/5/2015 9:54 AM View respondent's answers
11
1/5/2015 9:24 AM View respondent's answers
11
1/5/2015 9:11 AM View respondent's answers
8
1/5/2015 8:44 AM View respondent's answers
7
1/5/2015 8:13 AM View respondent's answers
11
1/5/2015 8:11 AM View respondent's answers
UI Test Automation @ $100/year
1/5/2015 7:22 AM View respondent's answers
7
1/4/2015 4:46 PM View respondent's answers
9
1/4/2015 3:24 PM View respondent's answers
Business Activity Monitoring
1/4/2015 9:43 AM View respondent's answers
Java 7 & 8 New Features
1/3/2015 9:38 PM View respondent's answers
Observe Don't Bake
1/3/2015 3:32 PM View respondent's answers
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .NET, you would normally use `GroupByUntil` or `GroupBy` if it's a finite sequence and simply apply `ToList` to each group. Then just sort *interactively*. I suspect it's the same in RxJava.

The reason is that reactive data-based sorting doesn't make sense. You can't sort a list until you have the whole thing, which means you need `OnCompleted`. If you're looking for a partial sort then you can use `GroupByUntil` as I've described above and the *until* part can define the partial sort boundaries.

Note that I had made [a PR for a complete set of OrderBy operators in Rx.NET](http://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/davedev/RxOrderBy/contribution/5169) and it was reviewed and rejected on the above premise. I had a brief Twitter discussion with Erik Meijer on the subject as well and he basically convinced me that a finite-sequence operator such as `OrderBy` doesn't belong in Rx. I was able to identify a potential performance reason for having it but ultimately I wasn't able to justify its use.

**Addendum:**

I'd just like to add that if your example shows how you're actually using Rx, then I think you shouldn't be using Rx here in the first place. Rx is for reactive processing of data, but you're just processing an in-memory list. In .NET, we'd use LINQ to Objects instead, but I don't know if there's any equivalent to that in Java.

Comment: What do you mean by sorting "interactively"? By the way, that example is just for learning by example.

Comment: By "interactive" I mean pull-based, not push-based. Interactive, not reactive. Synchronous, not asynchronous. For example, you could use the quick sort algorithm.